# PowerBI - New Card Visual cropped when published on Service from October 2023 Desktop version

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I found out today the new visual card is not published correctly on service if uploaded from the October 2023 version.

It was working peferctly with the previous version but now the publishing modifies it somehow by adding a glow effect and cropping the card.

Anyone having the same issue or knowing when it would be fixed?

Temporary solution: Online report modification on the service app is solving the problem.

Thank you